# Different t-value for the same data in R (nlme vs lme4 package)

Tags: t-test, p-value, lme4-nlme

I have two dependent variable Prime Type (five levels), and Prime Relatedness (two levels), and one dependent variable; Reaction Time (RT).
I have ran a linear mixed-effect model in R using the following formula for lme4 package:

```
data.mod1=lmer(RT~Related*PrimeType*(1|Subject)+(1|Item),mydata)
```

Then I ran a similar formula for nlme package

```
data.mod1.lme=lme(RT~Related*PrimeType, random=~1|Subject/Item,mydata)
```

Considering that these models are analyzing the same data set using linear mixed effect models, the t-test show different values! In fact, for one of the variables it shows a significant p-value in nlme model but not in lme4 package:

```
nlme.variable t=-1.98707 p-value=0.0470
lme4.variable t=-1.14    p-value=0.2917866*
```

*The p-value in lme4 is not calculated and sampMCMC is no longer available, I had to calculated using the following formula
2*(1 - pt(abs(x), df)) --> 2*(1 - pt(abs(-1.14), 7))

My question is that why are the t-values differ between the two packages. Do I need to change or add something in R to have both models show the same t-values? Also, is my calculation of the p-value wrong? If yes, what is the correct way for it to be calculated it?

EDIT: nlme experts - what is the correct code for the above mentioned formula to add cross random effect?

Comment: I think you should probably submit the "how do I specify crossed random effects" as a separate question on StackOverflow, if http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg10849.html doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given a reproducible example, but:

```
library(lme4)
library(nlme)
library(pbkrtest)

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
## see definition of KRSumFun below, taken from ?drop1.merMod:
## requires recent [development?] version of `lme4`:

packageVersion("lme4")  ## 1.1.2
drop1(fm1,test="user",sumFun=KRSumFun)

## Model: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)
## Method: Kenward-Roger via pbkrtest package
## 
## 
##        ndf ddf  Fstat    p.value F.scaling
## <none>                                    
## Days     1  17 45.853 3.2638e-06         1

fm2 <- lme(Reaction ~ Days , random = ~Days | Subject, sleepstudy)
anova(fm2)
##             numDF denDF   F-value p-value
##(Intercept)      1   161 1454.0766  <.0001
## Days            1   161   45.8534  <.0001
```

Note that this is a case (random-slopes model) where `lme` actually gets the **wrong** answer for the denominator degrees of freedom.

```
KRSumFun <- function(object, objectDrop, ...) {
       krnames <- c("ndf","ddf","Fstat","p.value","F.scaling")
       r <- if (missing(objectDrop)) {
           setNames(rep(NA,5),krnames)
       } else {
          krtest <- KRmodcomp(object,objectDrop)
          unlist(krtest$stats[krnames])
       }
       attr(r,"method") <- c("Kenward-Roger via pbkrtest package")
       r
    }
```

Comment: library(lme4) # I updated it and it is on version'1.0.4'
    library(pbkrtest)
    mydata.mod1=lmer(RT~Related*PrimeType*(1|Item)+(1|Subject),mydata)
    drop1(mydata.mod1,test="user",sumFun=KRSumFun)
    # I recieved the following message "Error in match.arg(test) : 'arg' should be one of "none", "Chisq""
    # @BenBolker what do you think the issue is?

Comment: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/afex/html/mixed.html

Comment: # Also, I have tried the following the above post:
mixed(mydata.mod1, mydata, type = 3, method = c("KR"))
# and 
m1 <- mixed(RT~Related*PrimeType*(1|Item)+(1|Subject), data = mydata)
# but it keeps telling me that "could not find function "mixed"" 
# am I missing the right package?

Comment: `mixed` is from the `afex` package -- you need to install and load it.  You need a more recent version of `lme4` (are you running R < 3.0?); try `install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")` (if you are running R >3.0 -- if not this will be more difficult)

Comment: You were right, I had to update R and re-install lme4. Both the mixed function from afex package and drop1 function worked well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I primarily use lme4, so you'll have to excuse me if this answer is incorrect. I believe you specified crossed-random effects in the lmer function call, but nested random effects in the lme function call. I'm not sure how to do crossed-random effects in lme, but perhaps [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme) or [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@stat.math.ethz.ch/msg10849.html) might yield some insight.

One other thing (unrelated), is that RTs usually possess a distribution with positive skew and could benefit from an inverse transformation. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77196/anova-with-huge-dataset-use-only-the-mean-for-each-condition/80288#80288) for a little more info.

Comment: I see, then I will look more into how the crossed-random effect is written in lme. @dmartin Since you use lme4, could you tell me how do you calculate the p-values? Also, what are the terms used in lme4 package to included nested random effects? I really appreciate it.

Comment: 1) Lme4 doesn't give you p-values, because for unbalanced, multi-level data, denominator degrees of freedom are unknown. Most packages give an approximation. Douglas Bates (lme4 author) instead chooses not to. More information found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html)
2) Nested effects really depend on the structure of the data, so it's hard for me to see what you want to specify from the example. [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) would be a good place to start