# specifying crossed random effects in glmmPQL / lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I'm trying to fit a GLMM on simulated response time data (continuous, positively skewed) obtained from hypothetical participants (`Subject`) responding to the same set of hypothetical items (`Item`), so it's a fully-crossed design. I intend to include several crossed-random effects for `Subject` and `Item`, so in `lme4` language, it would look like the following:

`glmer(y ~ x1*x2*z1 + (1+x1+x2|Subject) + (1|Item), family=Gamma("identity"), data=foo)`

However, as I read from Ben Bolker's GLMM FAQ (https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fn1), the estimation procedure used by `glmer` (adaptive Gauss-Hermite quadrature) can only handle up to 2-3 random effects. Indeed, running `glmer` on my simulated data  not only results in inevitable non-convergence but also takes such a long time to run.

Someone recommended to me to use `MASS::glmmPQL` instead because the cases in which penalized quasi-likelihood (PQL) would perform poorly (count/binomial DV, mean DV < 5) doesn't apply to my data (continuous DV, identity link, many items, and many subjects). Moreover, PQL could handle more random effects than GHQ; it could also allow for correlations of random effects to be estimated; and it estimates the model faster than GHQ. (I don't actually know about any of those being accurate characterizations of PQL and GHQ; would be happy to be corrected and pointed to the right direction.)

I initially thought that the response in this thread ([Specifying multiple (separate) random effects in lme](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme)) gave the answer, but it models the random effect for `Item` as if it was nested under `Subject`, but they're crossed (note `Item %in% Subject` in results of a test model (i.e., doesn't have the random effects I want as in the model I mentioned earlier) below):

```
> bar <- glmmPQL(y ~ x1*x2*z1, random=list(Subject=~1, Item=~1),
                 family=Gamma("identity"),data=foo)
> summary(bar)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
Data: foo 
AIC BIC logLik
NA  NA     NA

Random effects:
Formula: ~1 | Subject
        (Intercept)
StdDev:    88.78614

Formula: ~1 | Item %in% Subject
        (Intercept)     Residual
StdDev:    197.4256 0.0005360151

Variance function:
Structure: fixed weights
Formula: ~invwt 
Fixed effects: y ~ x1 * x2 * z1 
               Value Std.Error   DF  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 515.1268 13.382142 3735 38.49360  0.0000
x1          -27.4088  4.163655 3735 -6.58287  0.0000
x2          -18.1321  6.422738 3735 -2.82312  0.0048
z1          -26.6217 11.966715   48 -2.22464  0.0308
x1:x2         2.7502  5.884197 3735  0.46739  0.6402
x1:z1         4.0648  3.657627 3735  1.11132  0.2665
x2:z1         2.2683  5.685076 3735  0.39899  0.6899
x1:x2:z1      1.3081  5.183023 3735  0.25238  0.8008

               *snip results*

Number of Observations: 3791
Number of Groups: 
          Subject Item %in% Subject 
               50              3791
```

I was wondering if someone can point me to how I can specify the model such that the random effects of `Subject` and `Item` are truly crossed. Thanks!

Comment: Curious if you found an answer to this? I have the same question myself.