# r - 2-way Repeated Measures ANOVA - different degree of freedom among ezAnova, aov and lme

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I would like to run a simple repeated measures ANOVA with 2 factors (Food & Drink).

Let's have a dummy df:

```
nSubj = 10; nFood = 5; nDrnk = 2;
dummy <- data.frame(Subj = factor(rep(1:nSubj, each=nFood*nDrnk, time=1)),
                Food = factor(rep(letters[1:nFood],  each=nDrnk, time=nSubj)),
                Drnk = factor(rep(c("water","beer"), each=1, time=nSubj*nFood)),  
                Like = sample(0:10, size=nSubj*nFood*nDrnk, replace=T))
```

Using ezANOVA:

```
library(ez)
m1 <- ezANOVA(data=dummy, dv=Like, wid=Subj, within=c(Food, Drnk), detailed=F, type=3); m1

     Effect DFn DFd         F          p p<.05        ges
2      Food   4  36 0.3282034 0.85717626       0.01301648
3      Drnk   1   9 7.2461652 0.02472067     * 0.07354474
4 Food:Drnk   4  36 1.5834181 0.19974760       0.07367973
```

Using lme:

```
library(nlme)
m2 <- lme(Like ~ Food*Drnk, random = ~1|Subj/Food/Drnk, data=dummy, method = "ML"); anova(m2)

            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    45 288.81124  <.0001
Food            4    36   0.29673  0.8781
Drnk            1    45   7.14446  0.0104
Food:Drnk       4    45   1.78966  0.1476
```

Using aov:

```
m3 <- aov(Like ~ Food*Drnk + Error(Subj/(Food*Drnk)),data=dummy); summary(m3)

Error: Subj
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  9  72.45    8.05               

Error: Subj:Food
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Food       4   10.9   2.725   0.328  0.857
Residuals 36  298.9   8.303               

Error: Subj:Drnk
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
Drnk       1  65.61   65.61   7.246 0.0247 *
Residuals  9  81.49    9.05                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: Subj:Food:Drnk
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Food:Drnk  4   65.7   16.43   1.583    0.2
Residuals 36  373.7   10.38
```

The denDF in the lme is different: why? is my lme model correct?

**EDIT**: Since nSubj = 10; nFood = 5; nDrnk = 2 and it is a repeated measures, the dof should be: Food=(4,36); Drnk=(1,9); Food:Drnk=(4,36). Right? So, why does lme have different dof?

**EDIT 2**: following Sal's suggestion, I run aov with another error:

```
m4 <- aov(Like ~ Food*Drnk + Error(Subj/Food/Drnk),data=dummy); summary(m4)

Error: Subj
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  9  100.4   11.16               

Error: Subj:Food
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Food       4  10.74   2.685   0.319  0.863
Residuals 36 302.66   8.407               

Error: Subj:Food:Drnk
      Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Drnk       1   54.8   54.76   7.267 0.00984 **
Food:Drnk  4   65.1   16.29   2.161 0.08875 . 
Residuals 45  339.1    7.54
```

This is interesting, the results are the same of m2 with the Drnk variable ignored (?).

Next, Changing the order of the variables in the lme's random:

```
m5 <- lme(Like ~ Food*Drnk, random = ~1|Subj/Drnk/Food, data=dummy, method = "ML"); anova(m5)
            numDF denDF   F-value p-value
(Intercept)     1    72 117.06035  <.0001
Food            4    72   0.61245  0.6550
Drnk            1     9   0.36079  0.5629
Food:Drnk       4    72   0.21603  0.9287
```

The DenDFs of both Food and interaction are wrong... other combinations of lme's random are either wrong or gives error. Therefore, how can I model a 2-way Repeated Measures ANOVA using lme?

Any help is appreciated

Cheers

Comment: maybe this is useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/specifying-multiple-separate-random-effects-in-lme?

Comment: The solution for the lme model should be in the answer to [this Stack Exchange question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/repeated-measures-anova-with-lme-in-r-for-two-within-subject-factors).  I actually couldn't get the solution to work in lme.  It appears that the solution using lmer is much more straight-forward.

Comment: Also, be aware of the `type="sequential"` default in `anova.lme`.  This may not match the marginal sums of squares used in `ezANOVA` when `type=3`.

Comment: Hi Sal, thanks. Quoting from that answer: _`lme` from `nlme` does not compute the denominator degrees of freedom correctly._ If this is true, I get my answer :/

Comment: I don't think that's your answer in this case.  I think your lme is specifying a different model than your aov.  Change the error in the aov to `Subj/Food/Drnk`, and see what happens.

Comment: It seems that `Subj/Food/Drnk` means `Drnk` is nested in `Food` that, in turn, is nested in `Subj`...

Comment: The answer is that it isn't easy to model crossed random effects with `nlme`.  It's really designed for nested random effects.  One solution is to use `lme4` instead.  If you do so, you'll find that the degrees of freedom differ, but, for your example, the resultant *p*-values will be very similar to those from `aov`.

Comment: yes, doing `lmer(Like ~ Food*Drnk + (1|Subj) + (1|Food:Subj) + (1|Drnk:Subj), data=dummy)` both the _p_-values and Mean Sq are quite similar to 'aov'.  so, probably I should juts use lmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer mostly from comments.

The model you are seeking with the `nlme` package would have crossed random effects. Pinheiro and Bates (2000) discuss using the `lme` function with crossed random effects by invoking the `pdBlocked` and `pdIdent` objects.  It is not obvious how this is implemented for different designs, and, personally, I've had trouble implementing this approach following Pinheiro and Bates or solutions described online.

One approach is to use the `lme4` package, with which it is apparently easier to specify crossed random effects.  In the example below, the degrees of freedom from the `lmer` model are similar to those from the `aov` function.

However, you should be cautious expecting the results from a mixed effects model to be similar to ordinary least squares (OLS) tests.

References 
Pinheiro, J.C., and D.M. Bates. 2000. Mixed -Effects Models in S and S-Plus.

```
set.seed(1234)

nSubj = 10; nFood = 5; nDrnk = 2;
dummy <- data.frame(Subj = factor(rep(1:nSubj, each=nFood*nDrnk, time=1)),
                Food = factor(rep(letters[1:nFood],  each=nDrnk, time=nSubj)),
                Drnk = factor(rep(c("water","beer"), each=1, time=nSubj*nFood)),  
                Like = sample(0:10, size=nSubj*nFood*nDrnk, replace=T))

m4 <- aov(Like ~ Food*Drnk + Error(Subj/(Food*Drnk)),data=dummy)
summary(m4)

   ### Error: Subj
   ###           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   ### Residuals  9  39.69    4.41               
   ### 
   ### Error: Subj:Food
   ###           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   ### Food       4  29.04   7.260   0.854  0.501
   ### Residuals 36 306.16   8.504               
   ###
   ### Error: Subj:Drnk
   ###           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
   ### Drnk       1  86.49   86.49   18.35 0.00204 **
   ### Residuals  9  42.41    4.71
   ###
   ### Error: Subj:Food:Drnk
   ###           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
   ### Food:Drnk  4   57.2   14.29   1.412   0.25
   ### Residuals 36  364.4   10.12                     

library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

m7 = lmer(Like ~ Food*Drnk + (1|Subj) + (1|Food:Subj) + (1|Drnk:Subj), data=dummy)
anova(m7, ddf="Kenward-Roger")

   ### Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Kenward-Roger's method
   ###           Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
   ### Food       29.04    7.26     4    36  0.8681 0.49247  
   ### Drnk       86.49   86.49     1     9 10.3416 0.01056 *
   ### Food:Drnk  57.16   14.29     4    36  1.7086 0.16947

ranova(m7)
```

Comment: Hi Sal, thanks. I didn't know the lmerTest package. I'm happy with this solution. Furthermore, [Baayen et al., 2008, J Mem Lang](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749596X07001398) can be useful..